# Check for new/existing values and update in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, telerik

I have a SQL table with Project Column value as   'Project1,Project2,Project3'
I need to update this row if they select a different value like 'Project4' from the telerik dropdown list as 'Project1,Project2,Project3,Project4'

I get the value from the dropdown same as 'Project1,Project2,Project3',so I will send this as a paramter to SQL.

Suppose if they select 'Project5,Project1'...Project1 should not be added as its already there.

Can some one suggest how do I check for new and existing values and update accordingly.
My simple update is not working for this scenario.Kind of struck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure and use merge to `insert` or `update` as necessary like the example below

```
DECLARE @nameField    VarChar(50) = 'some data'

MERGE dbo.MyTable t
USING (SELECT @nameField [field]) s
    ON t.myData = s.field
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET t.myData = @nameField
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (myData)
    VALUES (@nameField);
```

If you want to limit redundant updates, e.g. if updating *Project Column* with the exact same data and block such updates, then you'll need to create an update [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to check and block the update.

Comment: Its not working...as they are not single values... I need to update this row if they select a different value like 'Project4' from the telerik dropdown list as 'Project1,Project2,Project3,Project4'

Comment: @user1046415 What does your table look like, and what does the data you are sending to your db look like?  From your question I understood it's one column you are checking against and if different update, if non existing insert, otherwise do nothing, is this not right?

Comment: Mytable has several columns but I am only updating one value which is the ProjectName.And data into the column gets inserted as 'Project1,Project2,Project3'.So I must be able to update it as 'Project1,Project2,Project3,Project4' if they select Project4 from the dropdown list.Hope it helps..

Comment: @user1046415 Is *Project1,Project2,Project3* what you insert into **ProjectName** column?  What is you key, how do you identify a row in the table?

Comment: I have ID as PrimaryKey...Yes we have such a scenario where employee can work for multiple projects.

Comment: @user1046415 In that case the answer above should work, you should be able to find the record to update/insert based on the `PK`, from there I'd recommend using a trigger to approve or reject the update based on the existing data, a simple comparison between the `MyTable.ProjectName` and `inserted.ProjectName` can tell you if it's modified data or not for this column. Otherwise, I guess you can try cascading the merge into testing PK then ProjectName